# How to count telerik Grid rows that has a specific value?

Tags: telerik, grid

I have a telerik grid on my asp.net application which has two column (ExitTime, EntryTime) showing time value.
I want count:

1. the total number of items in ExitTime which has null value.
2. the total number of items in EntryTime which has null value.
3. the total number of items in ExitTime which has a time value.
4. the total number of items in EntryTime which has a time value.
5. the total number of items where EntryTime has a time value but ExitTime has no value(null).
6. the total number of items where EntryTime & ExitTime both has no value(null).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That really should be aggregated using the data from the data source, rather than interpreted from the rows in the grid.